# New Base URL is not working

Tags: uri

I have a site "damo1.com" now I want to use my drupal site in "damo.com", so I just change $base_url in sites/default/settings.php. And I still can see my homepage very good, but I cannot check the others views or access to the site as user.

Do I need to do one more step? Thx

Comment: We can't quite know how are your servers and domains configured. Also, "cannot check the others" is broad. What exactly is happening?

Comment: I couldnt check all my "views" but now its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before migrate your site I/You needed to:

Disable clean URLs in the live site -
» Administer » Configuration »Clean URLs, disable and save.

Then in my/your new site enter with this:

**?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls**

And activate again Clean URL's, with this my/your site will reconize the clean url's

Answer (score 1):

1. In your **sites/default/settings.php** file, comment the $base_url line, you don't need to specify one, **Drupal** can do it for you.
2. In your **.htaccess**, uncomment **RewriteEngine on**
3. In the same file, **RewriteBase /** must be  also uncommented, and if your website is hosted under a subfolder of your root web folder, you must specify your folder  here. **Eg: RewriteBase /subfolder/**
4. Activate clean URL's in **admin/config/search/clean-urls**
5. In apache **httpd.conf** file, check if **mod_rewrite** is enabled

Answer (score 0):

try to remove $base_url from your settings.php ? Drupal is supposed to guess correctly your base url in your situation.